Changing the color when hovering
can I ask if what is the cause of my css code here, when I hovered over the class it display the background color, however the text color wont display it when I try to hover it the button.
 <li class="cards-carousel">
            <div class="img">
              <img
                src="img/adams-homes.png"
                draggable="false"
                alt="Adams Home"
              />
            </div>
            <h2>Adams Home</h2>
            <div class="links btn">
              <a href="#">View Floor Plans</a>
            </div>
 </li>

.cards-carousel .links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.cards-carousel .links a:visited {
  color: #000;
}

.cards-carousel .links {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #d4af50;

  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}

.cards-carousel .btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.9rem 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.cards-carousel .btn a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.cards-carousel .btn:before {
  background-color: #161443;
  color: #fff;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.cards-carousel .btn:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.cards-carousel .btn:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
}

https://jsfiddle.net/2pb8j3uq/1/#&togetherjs=9snABpHcsk
I tried to change everthing I can, I'm just new in coding and still learning. Thank you so much for help and guide to solve my questions

Which class exactly? Your css does not include anything with :hover state.

I added it here cards-carousel .btn:before

Order of elements are important if you are using position. Currently, your .cards-carousel .btn:before comes above your text, thus it is not visible. You can change the z-index as:
.cards-carousel .btn a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: inherit; 
}

So, your link will come above.


.cards-carousel .links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.cards-carousel .links a:visited {
  color: #000;
}

.cards-carousel .links {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #d4af50;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}

.cards-carousel .btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.9rem 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.cards-carousel .btn a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: inherit;
}

.cards-carousel .btn a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.cards-carousel .btn:before {
  background-color: #161443;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.cards-carousel .btn:hover:before {
  height: 100%;
}

.cards-carousel .btn:hover a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
<li class="cards-carousel">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="img/adams-homes.png" draggable="false" alt="Adams Home" />
  </div>
  <h2>Adams Home</h2>
  <div class="links btn">
    <a href="#">View Floor Plans</a>
  </div>
</li>




Great this really helps thanks a lot for informative.. I keep this noted thanks
